# Creating a fact table with Date key in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am working on my first datawarehouse

I have table

```
fact_xxx(
name,
age,
date_key
)
```

How to create this table in SQL Server?

With condition: `date_key` is always in this format

```
select year(getdate()) * 10000 + month(getdate()) * 100 + day(getdate())
```

How do I create such a table whenever name, age is inserted `date_key` gets incremented ?

Comment: Specify data type as date then insert getdate() into date_key column? Format may not be exact but it is more useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could write a function something like this !

```
create function Datekey1(@year1 int)
returns int
as
begin
declare @a int= year(@year1) * 10000 + month(@year1) * 100 + day(@year1)
end
return @year1
end;
```

Comment: I used this..thanks can you take look at my question??